# Add shapefile Polygons to Choropleth Map (Choroplethr)

Tags: r, choropleth, choroplethr

I would like to add a shapefile containing polygons to my choropleth map which i created using the Choroplethr package. 
The choropleth map was created with the following code:

`choro=county_choropleth(Change, title= "WeeklyChange",
state_zoom = continental_us,reference_map = F)+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("-3"="red4","-2"="red3","-1"="red1",
"0"="snow","1"="greenyellow","2"="green","3"="green3"))`

`plot(choro)`

`gold= readShapePoly("Gold")
gold_df= fortify(gold)
land= ggplot(data= gold_df,aes(x=long, y= lat, group=group))+
geom_polygon(colour="gold3")`

`plot(gold)`

Both objects appear correctly, however I cannot stack the gold plot on the choropleth map.
[Choropleth and gold map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i024M.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ari Lamstein for helping me out. Below is the code to add polygons

```
# Create Choropleth Map
`choro=county_choropleth(Change, title= "WeeklyChange",
state_zoom = continental_us,reference_map = F)+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("-3"="red4","-2"="red3","-1"="red1",
"0"="snow","1"="greenyellow","2"="green","3"="green3"))`

`#Import shapefile polygons
gold= readShapePoly("Gold")`

`#Create dataframe for ggplot
gold_df= fortify(gold)`

`#Combine Choropleth Map and shapefile dataframe
choro+geom_polygon(data= gold_df,aes(x=long, y= lat,group=group),fill="gold3")`
```